# Convert second column of a numpy array to imaginary

Tags: python, numpy

I want to convert the second column of a numpy array to imaginary.

Failed attempt:

```
>>> Z = np.array([[1, 2], [3, 4], [5, 6]])
>>> print(Z)
[[1 2]
 [3 4]
 [5 6]]

>>> Z[:, 1] = (Z[:, 1]) * 1j
ComplexWarning: Casting complex values to real discards the imaginary part
>>> print(Z)
[[1 0]
 [3 0]
 [5 0]]
```

Expected result:

```
[[1+2.j]
 [3+4.j]
 [5+6.j]]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Right now you have an array of integers. That will be difficult or impossible to convert to any kind of complex type in-place. The simplest solution is

```
Z = Z[:, 0] + Z[:, 1] * 1j
```

This will reduce the original dimension. You can preserve it using slices as [@SayandipDutta suggests](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58748866/2988730), or reshape to the size you want:

```
Z = (Z[:, 0] + Z[:, 1] * 1j).reshape(-1, 1)
```

A solution more in line with what you were trying would be possible if you had started with an array of floats like

```
Z = np.array([[1., 2.], [3., 4.], [5., 6.]])
```

or

```
Z = np.array([[1, 2], [3, 4], [5, 6]], dtype=float)
```

Now you can view the data as `np.complex`, based on the reasonably safe assumption that arrays are allocated in C order:

```
Z.view(dtype=np.complex)
```

This will preserve the shape of the original. You can optionally reduce the dimensionality with

```
np.sqeeze(Z.view(dtype=np.complex))
```

or simply

```
Z.view(dtype=np.complex).reshape(-1)
```

Comment: Small issue, this will convert `Z` to 1D array, `Z = Z[:, :1] + Z[:, 1:] * 1j` should be safer,

Comment: @SayandipDutta. How would that be any safer?

Comment: With your answer, the shape of `Z` will be `(3,)` instead of `(3,1)` as the OP requires.

Comment: @SayandipDutta. Thanks for the catch. I've addressed the problem in a couple of different ways.

Answer (score 2):

You can convert it to `complex` first:

```
>>> Z=np.array([[1, 2],[3, 4],[5, 6]])
>>> Z = Z.astype(complex)
>>> Z = Z[:,:1] + Z[:,1:]*1j
>>> Z
array([[1.+2.j],
       [3.+4.j],
       [5.+6.j]])
```

Comment: Nice. The `astype` call creates an unnecessary temp array.

Comment: Yes, correct, just wanted a way to show OP how to cast to complex, might be useful for other cases. Your answer is more comprehensive though. Reached my daily vote limit, couldn't upvote :D